# Issue with tailwind, how to prevent w-0 letting a modal overflow from the page?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an issue where I created a modal that slide from right to left, but and as soon as I use width 0:

```
<div
      className={`flex flex-col absolute right-0 top-0 h-full min-h-screen transition-width ease-in-out duration-300"  
        ${showModal ? 'w-144' : 'w-0'} 
        `}
    >
```

The modal overflow the main page as shown here below:
[image]

This is my component:

```
    import React from 'react';

interface ModalProps {
  showModal: boolean;
  setShowModal: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const Modal = ({ showModal, setShowModal }: ModalProps) => {
  const toggleExpand = () => {
    setShowModal(!showModal);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col absolute right-0 top-0 h-full min-h-screen transition-width ease-in-out duration-300"  
        ${showModal ? 'w-144' : 'w-0'} 
        `}
    >
      <div className="bg-inpay-green-700 h-20 flex items-center justify-between text-white">
        <div className="flex justify-between items-start ml-3">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-start mx-3">
            <p className="text-xs right-0">payouts</p>
            <h3>Customer</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-start mx-3">
            <p className="text-xs right-0">payouts</p>
            <h3>Customer</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-start mx-3">
            <p className="text-xs right-0">payouts</p>
            <h3>Customer</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center mr-3">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-end mx-3">
            <p className="text-xs right-0">EUR</p>
            <h3>50.00</h3>
          </div>
          <a onClick={toggleExpand} className=" w-4 h-4 block top-8 mx-3">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="19.536"
              height="19.536"
              viewBox="0 0 19.536 19.536"
            >
              <g
                id="Group_6419"
                data-name="Group 6419"
                transform="translate(1.768 1.768)"
              >
                <path
                  id="Path_9699"
                  data-name="Path 9699"
                  d="M1.25,17.248l16-16"
                  transform="translate(-1.25 -1.248)"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="#fff"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-width="2.5"
                />
                <path
                  id="Path_9700"
                  data-name="Path 9700"
                  d="M17.25,17.248l-16-16"
                  transform="translate(-1.25 -1.248)"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="#fff"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-width="2.5"
                />
              </g>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="bg-white h-full text-black flex justify-between overflow-hidden p-6 border border-inpay-black-haze-500">
        <div className="border border-inpay-black-haze-500 bg-inpay-black-haze-100  w-2/4">
          <p>TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div className="h-full w-2/4 ml-6">
          <div className="border border-inpay-black-haze-500 bg-inpay-black-haze-100 mb-6 h-40">
            <p>TEST</p>
          </div>
          <div className="border border-inpay-black-haze-500 bg-inpay-black-haze-100 mb-6 h-44">
            <p>TEST</p>
          </div>
          <div className="border border-inpay-black-haze-500 bg-inpay-black-haze-100 h-96">
            <p>TEST</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

I also tried to put overflow hidden on the parent as well as on the modal or use transition but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

First, `w-144` and `transition-width` are not a default class in Tailwind, you should add it in the configuration if you haven't. If that does not solve the problem, you can replace `width` class to `max width` and apply transition effect on it. It is the same [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css/8331169#8331169) that applies to transit the `height` property.

Example

```
<div
      className={`overflow-hidden w-full flex flex-col absolute right-0 top-0 h-full min-h-screen transition-all ease-in-out duration-300"  
        ${showModal ? 'max-w-7xl' : 'max-w-0'} 
        `}
    >
```

Comment: Thanks a lot saboshi69, the classes were already in the tailwind config:) I solved it with ${showModal ? 'w-152' : 'w-0 overflow-x-hidden'}  but I am not sure if it is the right approach